# Getting 'AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'' when calling split after a file is open and read

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I want to read and split each element in this file into a list so I can work with each number individually.

However whenever I use `split()`, I get an AttributeError.

This is the code:

```
f= open(r"C:\Users\yooni\Documents\Message.txt", "r")

numbers = f.split(",")
```

This is the error I get:

**AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'**

The file looks like this:

**48, 24, 0, 19, 17, 8, 19, 78, 58, 74, 65, 34, 43, 77, 52, 32, 54, 40, 49, 38, 38, 57, 36, 42, 83, 32, 32, 49, 49, 52, 65, 39, 29, 80, 0...**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't reading the file content to a string before trying to split it. That said, have you considered treating it as CSV? There's a standard library module for that...

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file, you get a `file` object. You need to call .read() on it to get the contents.

Comment: Yes now that I have read the file it has worked, i assumed that the "r" parameter when i open the file already means the file was read.

Comment: @ZakA Instead of assuming things, I recommend taking a look at the Python docs for [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). The `open` method returns a file object (as answered), and the `r` tells `open` how you want to access the contents of the file. You then have to use one of the `read` [method of file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to _actually_ read it.